# Web Programming Pre - Fill A Form

Tags: forms, post, web, client-server, mongoose-web-server

I am very new to using both a server - side and client - side at the same time with web programming. I have a simple page with two text fields, one is called `topTextField`, the other `bottomTextFeild`, and a submit button called `content`. When I press 'Submit' the data goes over to my [Mongoose](https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) server instance, it gets processed by a simple Lua script, and 
a link appears for the client with the auto - fill form data e.g `localhost:8080?topText=blah&bottomText=moreblah&content=Submit`, or one of the few variants I have tried, weather I manually enter this url, or put it in a `<a href...`, it does not seem to pre - fill the form data, even if I clear my cache. I know this seems like a simple task, but I am quite lost. How do I get the form data to pre - fill in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Use method=pst in form attribue like following

```
<form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="post">
.......
</form>
```

I guess the server needs post request to accept the data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I do have it like that.